# Node Js, websockets save connections in channels

Tags: node.js, websocket, channel

Hi I am using websockets with node js server, the npm module is ws. I have an array where I save all my connections but now I have to separate them so I did multidimensional array something like this:

```
users[channel1][user_id1] = ws_user_id1_connection
```

The question is when I have 1 user in multiple channels:

```
users[channel1][user_id1] = ws_user_id1_connection
users[channel2][user_id1] = ws_user_id1_connection
users[channel3][user_id1] = ws_user_id1_connection
```

From preformance point of view, is this ok?. or I can accomplish this in some other way? And if I leave it like this, Is that users[channel1],users[channel2],users[channel3], they would be only reference to the ws_user_id1_connection. I mean It's not going to add the all data about ws_user_id1_connection when I create new users[channelNew], but only reference to it. The Idea is that I would like to have something as rooms/channels and in each channel to have some connected users so they can talk each other. Is that the right way? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that `channel1` is a chat room, `user_id1` is the userid in the room, then yes, that's a good way to implement it, you should not create a different ws per channel. You will just need to add some information to the sent data so the client knows what is the room related to the message, something like:

```
{
  'room': 'channel1',
  'from': 'otherUser_id',
  'msg': 'some text message'
}
```

I would recommend not to use `channel` to refer a room because it can be confused with a ws channel. I´d also change the name of the variable ´users´ as it is not referencing users, I´d leave it like: `rooms[room_id1][user_id1] = ws_user_id1_connection`

Also, you may want to check [Socket.io](http://socket.io/), it is a good Nodejs library designed for that kind of applications.